# Access Union Query has truncated memo field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access UNION query, that is based on three subqueries, each of which has a memo field that contains long text.

In order for the three subqueries to work properly (i.e. displaying the full memo field text) I have already used the recommended workaround solution (First) by Allen Brown (http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html). However, these do not seem to work when I use UNION. The text gets truncated at 255 characters again.

**How can I get one query to display the full text with all records from my three subqueries?**

This is my current query:

````
FROM   _qry_publfinder_cb_other_advagreementno
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM   _qry_publfinder_cb_other_advagreementyes
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM _qry_PublFinder_CB_Rec;```
````

Comment: If you specify field lists instead of *, does something improve? I wont even ask, has your first query correct results :). Is your `union all` query final one or do you perform any aggregation over it? According to your linked article, this also may truncate memo fields.

Comment: all of the subqueries function properly and i've double checked that they contain the full text that i want. yes this would be the final summary query. i've tried experimenting with using UNION ALL on just the individual memo field, but no positive result

Comment: Have you some unique field (like id) inside those queries? I have no experience with your problem, but I would try `select id, memofield from ... union all ...`, in query pairs first. In some databases existence of unique field is helpful in some cases (sorry for vagueness), this is why I asked.

Comment: The table I'm getting the source data from is the only one in the DB that does not not have a unique id :-(

Comment: And about 'unioning' those queries pairwise? Does access kill memos then also?

Comment: I just gave it a try and it truncates the results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to create a workaround for this particular situation. As the finaly query will be called by a script under any circumstances, I created a temp table that the 3 subqueries will be appended to. This way the memo field is not truncated. It's a second best solution for sure, but it works.

```
DoCmd.Hourglass True
CurrentDb.Execute "qry_del_temp_PublFinder_CB"
CurrentDb.Execute "qry_app_PublFinder_CB_1"
CurrentDb.Execute "qry_app_PublFinder_CB_2"
CurrentDb.Execute "qry_app_PublFinder_CB_3"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_PublFinderUpload", acViewNormal
DoCmd.Hourglass False
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single table common to all three subqueries that contains your memo field, try linking it in after you've done the union, e.g.

```
SELECT UQ.FLD1, UQ.FLD2, UQ.FLD3, tbl_with_memos.memo_field
FROM 
(SELECT FLD1, FLD2, FLD3 
FROM   _qry_publfinder_cb_other_advagreementno
UNION ALL 
SELECT SELECT FLD1, FLD2, FLD3
FROM   _qry_publfinder_cb_other_advagreementyes
UNION ALL 
SELECT SELECT FLD1, FLD2, FLD3
FROM _qry_PublFinder_CB_Rec) AS UQ
INNER JOIN tbl_with_memos
ON UQ.FLD1 = tbl_with_memos.FLD1
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and I think it would have been a viable answer, except for the fact that the source table doesn't have a unique record identifier. Implementing one would have been more work than the workaround i finally went with. +1 for a solution that may help some one else though

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a documented 'feature':
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/union-query-truncates-the-field-contents-of-memo/f81ee760-ec69-4b5b-a709-6e533f8f66de

> A UNION query removes all duplicate records. Since a Memo field could
> contain billions of bytes, the developers chose to avoid the possibly
> very time consuming task of comparing one billion byte memo field to
> another billion byte memo field by truncating all memos to 255 bytes.
>
> If you don't need to deduplicate the records - i.e. if you're
> confident that the records in the different tables are already
> different - just use
>
> UNION ALL
>
> instead of UNION in the query. It won't try to deduplicate, it won't
> truncate, and as a bonus the query will run faster.

Comment: I'm using UNION ALL